# Javascript .replace() method failing in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, replace

Why does this not work in IE8?

```
var accordion = $(this),
    header = accordion.find(':header')[0],
    titleHTML = header.outerHTML,
    innerHTML = accordion.html().replace(titleHTML, '');
```

The `header` variable is populated, but `.replace()` does not find the string of HTML. It works in Chrome, FF etc but IE8 does not want to play.

I tried removing the element before building the `innerHTML` variable but that introduced more problems further down the execution path.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

---

**EDIT**

The rewrite worked with a bit of massage.

```
var accordion = $(this),
    header = accordion.find(':header').first(),
    titleHTML = header.prop('tagName'),
    titleLabel = header.text();

header.remove();

var innerHTML = accordion.html();
```

Essentially the two main changes were to getting the first element with `[0]` was a bit flaky and indeed removing the element first was the way to go.

Comment: What is `:header` supposed to target? Is there such a pseudo selector!

Comment: @adeneo see [header-selector](http://api.jquery.com/header-selector/)

Comment: There is http://api.jquery.com/header-selector/ 
It is working to populate the 'header` var.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - There it is, didn't bother searching, but I don't think I've ever seen that used before, and it was added in 1.2 ?

Comment: @adeneo me neither... but has seen it else where

Comment: Can you share the targeted html what what is accordion referring to

Comment: @adeneo Hmmm, yet it is working ?! Might try a little rewrite to be in line with v1.10.2

Comment: But why would you remove the element by replacing the HTML directly like that? See my answer, and if you just need the HTML, clone, remove, return etc !

Comment: Doing string replacement using two separate HTML serializations isn't very reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(this).find(':header').first().remove();
```

It seems that's basically what you're doing, find any header elements, get the native DOM node of the first one, then getting the `outerHTML`, and replacing it in `this`, trying to remove it, and it seems like a strange way to do it.

Comment: Yeah going to rewrite this now. I didn't write the original js, just trying to debug it. Thanks for your answer :-)